# Ruby on rails currency switcher for whole site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency, money-rails

I've been searching for hours and viewed all google results one by one... Read about RubyMoney, Money-Rails. I'm new to rails and I still can't understand **how to get a currency switcher for my whole Ruby on Rails app.**

1. In my Gemfile

   ```
   gem 'money-rails' 

   gem 'json'

   gem 'bigdecimal'
   ```

2. bundle
3. Created config/initializers/money.rb

   ```
   MoneyRails.configure do |config|
     config.default_currency = :eur
   end
   ```
4. `<%= humanized_money_with_symbol (item.item_price) %>` formats that number as a currency in the view.
5. How do I get a currency selector like Airbnb for instance to change all the prices of the website with automatic rate update from EU bank or google? I can't understand the RubyMoney documentation regarding this...

Comment: You're talking about currency exchange factors, not just currency presentation issues. Sites like that download exchange rates from somewhere and save that in a table used to convert when displaying values.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on what information I should search for to get started? Can it be done only with Money-Rails or is it much more complex?

Comment: MoneyRails does provide to ability to convert exchange rates through Banks [See here](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money#exchange-rate-stores) for a better idea

Comment: In other Gits it was quite easy to follow the instructions but here I don't know where should I add those lines? In a newly created models/money.rb or in config/initializers/money.rb ? 

Then they say "Stores must implement the following interface: " - I don't know neither how to use that. 

Just knowing the location where to add these could really unblock me in the comprehension of how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's where I would do as starting point.

1) Add to **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'google_currency'
```

2) Add to **config/initializers/money.rb**:

```
MoneyRails.configure do |config|
  config.default_currency = :eur

  # set default bank to instance of GoogleCurrency
  Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.ttl_in_seconds = 86400
  config.default_bank = Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.new
end
```

3) Add a currency selector somewhere in **application layout** or wherever you think it should go with all currencies you are interested in (:usd, :eur, etc.). Use either `on change` **javascript** event of this select box or a button to trigger a rails action that saves the selected currency on a session variable (let's call it from now on **session[:currency]**) and that also refreshes the current page (in case you are showing some prices on the current page - if you're using just a button a simple `redirect_to :back` would do otherwise if your response is in **js** format use `window.location.reload();`). Action would look something like this:

```
def save_currency
  session[:currency] = params[:currency]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
  end
end
```

And on your **routes.rb** (replace controller for whatever you want) something like this:

```
post '/controller/save_currency', to: 'controller#save_currency'
```

Just the form with select box and submit button missing - do this as you please :)

4) Add a helper method to render prices (I'm assuming all your price attributes are defined as `monetize` using the `money-rails` gem). All prices that you want to show on your site should use this method to be rendered on a view. Method would look something like this (you can put it on your **application_helper.rb** if you don't see other place it would fit better):

```
def converted_price(price)
  if session[:currency].present?
    humanized_money_with_symbol(price.exchange_to(session[:currency]))
  else
    humanized_money_with_symbol(price)
  end
end
```

This is a simplified version, you should also add some exception handling [look at google_currency gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/google_currency) for more documentation on this.

5) On all the views where you want to print a price, use a code similar to this (I'm using the same example as you did):

```
<%= converted_price(item.item_price) %>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Rodrigo, I try this asap!

Comment: @Sébastiend'Olbecke sure, np! If answer was helpful remember to mark as correct answer and/or vote it up :)